# Sagemaker endpoint(with VPC) url accessible from internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have created a model with VPC, Private subnet, and appropriate security group. The endpoint URL can, however, be reached through the internet though failing due to the lack of security token

Things I need clarification on now are

1. Is there a way to avoid the URL being accessible from the internet
2. Are we not charged for requests failed on AUTH(like for API Gateway)
3. Does that make our deployment vulnerable to any attacks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not hitting your endpoint, but the endpoint of AWS SageMaker runtime. This endpoint is checking all the permissions to access your hosted model, and only if the credentials and requirements are met, the request is forwarded to your instances and models.

Therefore, you can't prevent this URL from being accessible from the Internet, but at the same time, you don't need to protect it or pay for it. AWS has a high level of security on these endpoints, and I don't think that you have a more secure way to protect these endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm confused because of the contents of some official blogs https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/load-test-and-optimize-an-amazon-sagemaker-endpoint-using-automatic-scaling/ which required Lambda and API GW , why is it required when the endpoint itself is managed?. Ofcourse discounting the obvious cases where we need pre-processing and custom authorizers

Comment: The complexity of signing the request to the endpoint is usually solved by the combination of API-GW (and its various authentication methods) and Lambda (with its IAM role permission mechanism). You can also use Cognito for the temporary credentials (with its authentication mechanism). A lot of options, but none is trivial like calling a REST endpoint.

Comment: Got it. But if we are invoking the endpoint using client SDK then API GW and Lambda becomes redundant right?

Comment: Exactly. If you have the SDK, you probably have a good chain to provide the needed credentials to call the sagemaker API of invoke_endpoint.